# How to concant values of loop into variable for returning in C

Tags: c, function, loops, return, popen

I'm having a little big problem with this. What I need to do is create a function that returns a string (receiving another string as parameter). This function should generate a encrypt (sha256) from the input. This is my horrible code and I will explain (or I'll try to)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>        
#include <string.h>                                                     

//not sure if this is the correct way to declare a string function 
//with string input parameter, but works with a dummy return
const char* Encrypt (char* Arg1)                                                                     
{  
    //varaible to generate command 
    char command[128];
    //variable to store the result
    char result[256];
    //creating command with input parameter
    snprintf(command, sizeof command, "echo -n %s | sha256sum | cut -c1-64",Arg1);  

    //popen varaible
    FILE *fpipe;
    //valdiating popen
    if (0 == (fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command, "r")))
    {
        perror("popen() failed.");
        exit(1);
    }

    //here is my problem
    char c = 0;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof c, 1, fpipe))
    {
        //when i print te "c", it shows correctly in a line
        printf("%c", c);
        //but I want to store in "result" variable for using as return

        //this doesnt work
        snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%s", c);   

        //this neither
        char c2[4];
        strcpy(c2, &c);
        strcat(result,c2);
        snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%s",c);    
    }

    printf("%c", result);

    pclose(fpipe);
    //return result; not working
    return "not woring";
}
```

Hope u can help me

Comment: `%s` is for null terminated strings, not for single characters. Use `%c` in `snprintf` as well.

Comment: done, but `printf("%c", result)` still not showing my encrypted value

Comment: As far as I can tell, your problem is not understanding how `printf` and `snprintf` work.   Most of the code does not make sense and I would not expect it to work -- what exactly are you trying to do with these lines in the while loop?

Comment: @Hogan Im trying to concat c variable into result variable for using later as return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok if that is what you want to do just add it to the string as an array:

```
char c = 0;
resultindex = 0;
while (fread(&c, sizeof c, 1, fpipe))
{
    //when i print te "c", it shows correctly in a line
    printf("%c", c);
    //but I want to store in "result" variable for using as return

    result[resultindex] = c;
    resultindex++;
}
result[resultindex] = 0;
printf("%s", result);
```

> I didn't test-- it might have bugs

Also, you really should check and make sure that resultindex never gets bigger than 256

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY!

Comment: You are my hero bro, working on this for 4 horas at least. No problem with with result index, sha256 is fixed to 256

Comment: It seems like it would be a lot cleaner to just let fread put the data in the array in the first place: `fread(result + resultindex, 1, 1, fpipe)` . The intermediate variable is probably discarded by the compiler, but it really serves no purpose but to obfuscate the code.  (I suppose some would argue that it makes the code more clear, but that is incorrect.)

Comment: But why use `fread` at all if you're only going to read 1 octet?  Either do `fread( ..., 1, 256, fpipe)` or use `fgetc`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I tried this `fread(result + resultindex, 1, 256, fpipe);`, removing while, is that what u mean? not working for me, can u clarify that?, and what about fgetc? how can I use that? Sorry but I'm newbie on C, just 2 days programming in it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell -- all of your points are good, I was assuming this was in a bigger context (eg read one char hash it put the result in a buffer) and this was just a test to see if it was being read correctly.

Comment: @WesleyRomero Not quite.  If you read 256 chars, just read them directly into result with no loop: `fread(result, 1, 256, fpipe)`.  (Check the return value).  You only need resultindex if you read one char at a time in a loop.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I tested like this `fread(result, 1, 256, fpipe);` but is not saving nothing.